# Validate redux form input field when user is entering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, redux, redux-form

Is there any way to validate an input field in the redux form when the user enters a value? All my validation are working when I click out or press the submit button. I want my validations to run when the user is typing. My code for the field is this:

```
<div className="fieldRow noMargin">
            <Field
              id={FIRST_TIME_OTP_NUMBER}
              name={FIRST_TIME_OTP_NUMBER}
              component={InputTextField}
              className="text xxs"
              classNameInvalid="text xxs error"
            />
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if field is `active` from metadata(props under the meta key), and show error if its value is true.

```
const renderField = ({input, label, type, meta: {active, touched, error, warning}}) => (
    <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <div>
            <input
                {...input}
                placeholder={label}
                type={type}
                onFocus={input.onFocus}
            />
            {(active || touched) &&
            ((error && <span>{error}</span>) ||
                (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

NOTE: It will only work if you are passing `onFocus` to your input element.

> [Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/81ro47mmm9)